Applying batch processing in QGIS Raster Calculator
I have 30 raster files from 1981 to 2010. Every raster has 12 bands, again corresponding to dates from June 1 to June 12. I want to calculate the mean for all the bands from 1981 to 2010.
Normally, I would have manually clicked on the bands via "Raster calculator" but since there are a total of 360 bands in total, it's a little cumbersome.
Is there a way where I can batch process the mean calculation?

For the raster calculator, you need an expression like this:
"raster_1981@1" + "raster_1982@1" + "raster_1983@1" + (...) 
+ "raster_2008@12" + "raster_2009@12" + "raster_2010@12"

You can use QGIS expressions to create such a string and than copy/paste it in raster calculator. The expression gets all layers, using the variable @layers, returns their layernames and concatenates all of them with a series of numbers for the bands: 1 to 12, in your case.
Open a new QGIS project with the only layers loaded being the rasters you want. Then go to Menu Processing -> Toolbox -> Field Calculator. See below for the expression that creates the string you want: copy it from the Preview at the bottom (right click) and insert it into the raster calculator.

array_to_string (
    array_foreach(
        generate_series(1,12),
        with_variable(
            'no',
            @element,
            array_to_string (
                array_foreach(
                    @layers,
                    '"'  || 
                    layer_property (@element,'name')
                    || '@' || @no  || '"'
                ),
                '+'
            )
        )
    ),
    '+'
)


Save the bands as separate raster files, than use Menu Processing -> Toolbox -> Cell statistics. Select all your layers in the tool, set statistics to Mean define a reference layer (for the extent) and run it.
